# How to fix Horizontal viewport was given unbounded height

Tags: flutter

Error: Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.

1. When I wrap TabBarView with Container and provide with specific height thier is no errorr.
2. But I need the container to expand according to the ListViewBuilder.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class classA extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _classAState createState() => _classAState();
}

class _classAState extends State<classA> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(kDefaultPadding),
                height: 40,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 80,
                child: TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                  indicator: BoxDecoration(color: kSecondaryColor),
                  tabs: <Widget>[Text('A'), Text('B'), Text('C')],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
                controller: ScrollController(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: 7,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => _ACard()),
            ListView.builder(
                controller: ScrollController(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: 5,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => _BCard()),
            ListView.builder(
                controller: ScrollController(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: 8,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => _CCard())
          ])
        ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it use CustomScrollView and SliverList

this is my Code

```
return CustomScrollView(
  slivers: <Widget>[
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection(_id).snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) =>
                SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) =>
                      customCardList(snapshot.data.documents, index),
                  childCount:
                      snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.documents.length : 0,
                ))),
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('festival$_id').snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) =>
                SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) =>
                      customMyCardList(snapshot.data.documents, index),
                  childCount:
                      snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data.documents.length : 0,
                ))),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to wrap TabBarView with `Flex()` instead of Container

```
Flex(
  fit: Flexfit.loose,
  child: TabBarView(
    //etc
  ),),
```

Comment: Getting same exception

Comment: Give me a minute i will check it out on my machine

Comment: @RahulKavati do you have a repo for this where I can get the code ?

Comment: widget we use is Flexible,  to use fit . error : RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

Comment: I can't really get your code to run as is on my machine.  Usually you're asked to provide a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: That's just the code that's in your question. Doesn't work. It depends on code defined elsewere.

Based on the info you provided I would say:
Try to set `Column( mainAxisAlignment: ` as well
Try to remove `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`

Comment: join me in this chatroom:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/218797/flutter-question?tab=general

Comment: I already used strech in cross axis alignment, should I want to add _Acard widget

Comment: i can't join chatroom because I dont have 20 reputations itseems

Comment: ah ok. Well it's difficult to help you my friend. You should aim to provide a small example that someone else could just copy paste and run next time.   

I can only give you advice. This type of error can often be fixed with `Expanded` widget or `Flexible` widget. Good luck.

Comment: can you check once again my repo